# Get the nearest/lowest Date SQL

Tags: sql, date

I have four dates with a different prices for each date:

```
10/01/2011  $25
10/08/2011  $50
11/17/2011  $100
12/23/2011  $150
```

SQL:

```
SELECT price FROM MyTable WHERE MyDate <= '10/12/2011'
```

PROBLEM: This query returns  $25 and $50. I need it to give me the nearest date only...
How can i have it return only the $50?

Comment: what SQL dialect (Microsoft SQL, Oracle, mySQL)   The answer below is for Microsoft SQL which might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT top 1 price FROM MyTable WHERE MyDate <= '10/12/2011' order by MyDate desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (in SQL Server)

```
SELECT TOP 1 price
FROM MyTable
WHERE myDate <= getDate() 
ORDER BY myDate DESC
```

Try this (in mySQL)

```
SELECT price
FROM MyTable
WHERE myDate <= now()
ORDER BY myDate DESC
LIMIT 1
```